# OOP parameter values equal to null

Tags: php, oop, methods, constructor, null

I'm just new in learning OOP. I've read many articles so far and tried some tutorials. I just wonder why when declaring parameter on a constructor some values should be nulled.

```
    function __construct($hostname = NULL, $username = NULL, $password = NULL, $database = NULL)
    {
        $this->hostname = !empty($hostname) ? $hostname : "";
        $this->username = !empty($username) ? $username : "";
        $this->password = !empty($password) ? $password : "";
        $this->database = !empty($database) ? $database : "";
    }
```

like this. I really want know.

Comment: ($hostname = NULL, $username = NULL, $password = NULL, $database = NULL) this is use for the passing value to the variable when the object of the class created and the parameter not supply in it at that time it will assign null value and the object is created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping argument as NULL would make the function run even if all the parameters are not passed during function call.

For example, if a function expects 3 arguments and you supplied only 2 and in function definition the third parameter is not assigned as NULL, the function will throw an error.

Comment: make sense. thanks. I'll just accept this after 10mins. Unable to accept this time.

Answer (score 2):

> I just wonder why when declaring parameter on a constructor some
>   values should be nulled.

These are **NOT** required to be nulled.

They are nulled as a [default value for the parameter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default). For example for the function given by you in the example, can be called in one of the five ways:

1. With no arguments
2. With $hostname
3. With $hostname, $username
4. With $hostname, $username, $password
5. With $hostname, $username, $password, $database

One needs to be careful that it is not possible to call the function with $hostname, $password and let the function assume default value of $username.

Comment: ah., I see. My bad for stating that. Because I saw articles doing that. Not because it's required but for good pracitice, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

This is a constructor with default values, If the parameters are not passed to _construct method it will assign the NULL values to the variables. So this means its not necessary to pass a parameters to this constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is to facilitate you to initiate the class without passing any of the parameter

```
function __construct($hostname = NULL, $username = NULL, $password = NULL, $database = NULL)
```

this signature tells that you can optionally pass parameters suppose your `Class A{}` has this constructor you can optionally initiate it in following ways

```
$t = new A();
$t1 = new A('locathost','user1','pw1', $db_connection);
$t2 = new A('localhost');
```

these all initializations will be valid.